# Java no such element exception

Tags: java

I am new to Java and cannot figure out where I am going wrong with my code. The program is supposed to take a couple words input as a single string with a comma and print them out as two separate words without the comma. It is supposed to print out an error message if there is no comma as well. Entering "q" will quit the program. It works perfectly when a "q" is entered. It also works when there is no comma, however, after the output it adds the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
at ParseStrings.main(ParseStrings.java:16)
```

Also, the program won't work when there is a comma input, but when I comment out the part about the comma in the code, it works but gives the above error message. Any assistance in showing me my errors will be greatly appreciated. Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ParseStrings {
public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      String userInput = "";
      String firstWord = "";
      String secondWord = "";
      boolean inputDone = false;
      boolean noComma = false;

      System.out.println("Enter input string or q to quit: ");

      while (!inputDone) {

         userInput = scnr.nextLine();

         if (userInput.equals("q")) {
             System.out.println("   Exiting.");

             inputDone = true;
         }
         else {
            while (!noComma) {
               if (userInput.indexOf(',') < 0) {
                  System.out.println("Error: No comma in string");

                  noComma = true;
               }
               else {
                  firstWord = userInput.substring(0, userInput.indexOf(','));
                  firstWord = firstWord.trim();

                  secondWord = userInput.substring(userInput.indexOf(',') + 1, userInput.length());
                  secondWord = secondWord.trim();

                  System.out.println("First word: " + firstWord);
                  System.out.println("Second word: " + secondWord);
                  System.out.println();
               }
            }
         }

      }

      return;
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code using your debugger to evaluate your program state when the error occurs?

Comment: When I run this code, I don't get the error messages you describe - I just get an infinite loop.

Comment: Dave, I did not step through the code. That probably should have been my first troubleshooting step. I will from now on. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the while loop:

```
           while (!noComma) {
```

It will be infinite because noComma won't be set unless there are no commas in the input.  The if statement that you have after that handles this condition the way I think you want:

```
           if (userInput.indexOf(',') < 0) {
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Code if i typed a String with no comma output is correct but if again i typed with comma or without comma it stuck in the infinite loop and if I terminate the program it is giving the exception.It is Thrown by various accessor methods to indicate that the element being requested does not exist. now let me show the error in your code

```
while (!inputDone) {userInput = scnr.nextLine();

     if (userInput.equals("q")) {
         System.out.println("   Exiting.");

         inputDone = true;
     }
     else {
        while (!noComma) {
           if (userInput.indexOf(',') < 0) {
              System.out.println("Error: No comma in string");

              noComma = true;
           }
```

when i typed without comma it came to first else and due to condition match it entered in noComma while loop and with printing the message it set the noComma flag now it can not enter in the else as the very first while condition is false so it will now never go to the else condition so now it is just checking this condition

```
   while (!inputDone) {userInput = scnr.nextLine();

     if (userInput.equals("q")) {
         System.out.println("   Exiting.");

         inputDone = true;
     }
```

with a infinite while loop which is taking the input but just searching for the "q" so when you terminate this program by Ctrl+c it will end with that Exception.

Please Correct me If I am wrong anywhere.

Comment: Thanks! I'm taking an online java class and I didn't get this lesson very much but the way you explained it cleared it up. Thanks again!